# Sistema de sessão em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Existe, em Python, um sistema de sessão como existe no PHP?

Preciso fazer um controle de acesso para uma aplicação desenvolvida em Python que utiliza banco de dados. Já desenvolvi um projeto semelhante (porém web) com PHP e utilizei seu recurso de sessão e achei muito prático e, por isso, queria implementar algo semelhante nesta nova aplicação.

Obs.: este não é um projeto web, mas sim, uma aplicação local.

Comment: Depende de como vc vai acessar o banco. Eu, se for desenvolver algo com "python puro", não penso mais que uma vez e ja escolho [SQLAchemy,](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) Se a app ainda vai ser desenvolvida, considere analisa-lo. [Aqui está a documentação para o uso de "Session".](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session.html)

Comment: A ideia é usar o SQLAlchemy, pois já havia utilizado em aplicações anteriores e gostei bastante do desempenho, principalmente com uma grande massa de dados (o que não é o caso)!

Comment: Então está resolvido. :-)